# What problems arise from upgrading mysql 5.5 x86 to mysql 5.5 x64?

Tags: mysql, iis, phpmyadmin, upgrade, windows-server-2008-x64

I have a windows server 2008 R2 x64 with mysql 5.5 x86 (not my install).

I want to upgrade to mysql 5.5 x64.

What issues will I have with everything else?

- PHP
- phpMyAdmin
- IIS
- Websites in PHP
- mysql logins
- etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered I though I would give my own feedback on how the upgrade went.

After the upgrade all the system DBs were reset which would be OK if they didn't have all the stored procedures, triggers and functions saved in it.
Also beware that logins are also saved there!

Then I had to fetch backup data to replace that data but my mysqldump backups has 2 problems:

1. Didn't backup the mysql db(system) with logins and triggers, functions and stored procedures.
2. Didn't backup the stored procedures, triggers and functions within the dump of the corresponding db because that is mysql standard procedure.

When doing such upgrades and for future backup knowledge here are my advices:

- Always backup the the mysqldump of EVERY db including system ones! (include logins, etc.)
- if using mysqldump use the `--routines` argument to include triggers, functions and stored procedures.
- always have a full backup of the files (you can use it if all else fails)
- beware that updating removes the users, if you wish backup them up beforehand.